# What does N-day correlation mean?

Tags: statistics, correlation, time-series

I have a stock price data for each day for stocks A and B for 5 years. I am asked to calculate: 1-week, 1-month, 3-month and the 1-year correlation between them.

I am puzzled as to the definition. Do I need to consider prices with the gap of 1-week (for example) to calculate 1-week correlation and similarly for others? But this means there are several ways I can start from the first day, the second day, so on...

Can someone clarify this, please?

Comment: They perhaps mean correlations with regard to different time windows.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Do I have to take sample from the price list with an interval of 1-week and then calculate the correlation?

Comment: yes this is what I mean. Therefore as the time window rolls the correlation changes too.

Comment: I am asked to give one-number but as you suggest the correlation changes as the time-window rolls -- this is what makes me confused

Comment: actually I share your confusion. I think they should be multiple values (a time series in a sense) instead of a single value. More context is needed to determine what they precisely refer to.

Comment: In addition, as a possibly tangential comment, making satisfactory estimates of correlations between stock prices is *hard* and usually involves much more sophisticated methodology than directly calculating the sample correlations. A rich amount of research (e.g. BARRA risk model handbooks) has been done  on  this seemingly innocuous problem.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I will see if I can get further insight on to this problem

Comment: Thanks to Google: Perhaps look at [_this_](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~adamodar/New_Home_Page/invfables/pricepatterns.htm).